# Passing variable into Firestore document path

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to reference a variable that I am storing the users UID to in a document reference to Cloud Firestore. The path doesn't seem to read a string though. I have tried two different way and both ways give me errors. How would you pass a variable string into a Cloud Firestore document/collection path?

---

I am getting the UsernameID from the database with:

```swift
UsernameID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

---

```swift
var UsernameID = String()

let ref = db.collection("user/\(UsernameID)/account").document("created")
        ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                print("User Exists")
            } else {
                print("User does not exist in firestore")
            }
        }
```

Throws error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid path (user//account). Paths must not contain // in them.'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

```swift
var UsernameID = String()

let ref = db.collection("user").document(UsernameID).collection("account").document("created")
        ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                print("User Exists")
            } else {
                print("User does not exist in firestore")
            }
        }
```

Throws error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but user has 1'
```

---

I have also tried storing the uid as a DocumentReferce but it failed to store a string as a DocumentReference.

```swift
let UsernameID = DocumentReference!
```

Comment: It looks like your code is passing an empty string as the id of a document.  That's never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are authenticating correctly, here's what you want to do to access a document stored in Firestore. Suppose the structure is

```
users //collection
   uid //document
      name //field within the document
```

and the code to read the name field

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let collectionRef = self.db.collection("users")
let userDoc = collectionRef.document(uid)
userDoc.getDocument(completion: { document, error in
     if let err = error {
         print(err.localizedDescription) //document did not exist
         return
     }

     if let doc = document {
         let name = doc.get("name")
         print(name)
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your top example

```
db.collection("user/\(UsernameID)/account")
```

It seems that you are not requesting your user collection. This is why you are getting the error about \ in collection names. The user collection should be something like this

```
let ref = db.collection("user").document(UsernameID)
        ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                print("User Exists")
            } else {
                print("User does not exist in firestore")
            }
        }
```

The .document should get the user document corresponding to the UsernameID passed. To get at a property you would need to access it via the document variable.

Comment: The OP is using *Firestore* not the *Real Time Database*

Comment: You overlooked how UsernameID is defined so if the OP uses that, they will continued to receive the same error.